# Display custom post types with custom date field value (before today) & order by custom date field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, query-posts, meta-query, order

I'm trying to display custom post types with custom date field value being before today. It works OK for showing posts before today, but the order is only based on post date. I want to have the result ordered by `meta_key`.

I tried the following code and I don't understand why it doesn't work:

```
query_posts( array(
  'post_type'    => 'soiree',
  'orderby'      => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'   => 'date_de_concert',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key'            => 'date_de_concert',
           'posts_per_page' => '-1',
           'value'          => date( 'Y-m-d' ),
           'compare'        => '<',
           'type'           => 'DATE',
           'orderby'        => 'value',
           'order'          => 'DESC',
        )
    )
) );
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but `meta_query` should not include `posts_per_page`, `order` or `orderby`. It should only have `key`, ` value`, `compare`, and `type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use WP_Query (for more info read "[When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)"), try this way:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'soiree',
  'post_status'    => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'orderby'        => 'date_de_concert',
  // you don't need 'meta_key' => 'date_de_concert' when using meta_query
  //'meta_key'     => 'date_de_concert',
  'order'          => 'DESC',
  'meta_query'     => array(
                        array(
                          'key'     => 'date_de_concert',
                          'value'   => strtotime( 'today' ),
                          'compare' => '<'
                        )
                      )
);

$concert_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $concert_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $concert_query->have_posts() ) : $concert_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have the same problem. My custom posts are displayed by order based on publish date but not meta_key.
Everything goes right for my first loop compared with date after today, but it doesn't work for this loop compared with date before today. 
If you have an idea... Thank you.

Comment: @guiyom84 I modified the answer, be sure to return the correct keyname `'date_de_concert'`, tell me if you need more help

Comment: Please note: you don't need `'meta_key'  => 'date_de_concert'` when using `meta_query`.

Comment: @Fayaz you are right, I modified the answer